# spa + water + marble spa cover + statue + 4 people = 3,500 #

Tags: wood

spa + water + marble spa cover + statue + 4 people = 3,500 #
55" width rests on floor covering 4 or 5  2 x 10,s of Douglas fir.
Safe?

Comment: NO. Unless we get some actual words giving us some details. **It Is incumbent on you to provide as much info as possible it you want an informed answer**. AND Marble spa cover ??

Comment: The support on floor covering? Is not clear to me. Taking the tour will help you understand our format.

Comment: What is span of 2x10’s?? What is area of deck? What is 55”?